# Achieve Truncate and Copy in single transaction using Python + Redshift

Tags: python, amazon-redshift

I do realize that Redshift commits the transaction in which it is run.

But I wanted to achieve something like:

```
BEGIN TX;
TRUNCATE TABLE t1;
COPY FROM S3;
rollback;
```

But I was wondering if there is a way to achieve a similar behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In Redshift `TRUNCATE` performs an implicit commit and therefore cannot be run inside an explicit `BEGIN..END` transaction.

You can consider using either of the following inside your transaction as an alternative:

1. `DELETE FROM t1;`
2. `CREATE TABLE t2 (LIKE t1); DROP TABLE t1; ALTER TABLE t2 RENAME TO t1;`